# reactive form is not valid even though entering the values in fields in angular 6

Tags: validation, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have login reactive form and added validations to form fields.
Once the user entered the value in form fields it should update the form value on the screen as I'm displaying form.value and also it should display the form status too. Both form value and status are not changing.
Nothing happened.

**html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form class='form' [formGroup]='loginForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
          <div *ngIf="f.username.touched && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <div *ngIf="f.password.touched && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
           </div>
          </form>
          <p>Form value: {{loginForm.value | json}}</p>
          <p>Form value: {{loginForm.status | json}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**ts file**

```
import { ObjectMethod } from '@babel/types/lib';
import { AuthService } from './../auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

 loginForm: FormGroup;
 returnUrl: string;

 constructor(
   private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
   private authService: AuthService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        username: ['', [ Validators.required]],
        password: ['', [ Validators.required]]
    });
}
//convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get f() {
  return this.loginForm.controls;
}

onSubmit() {
console.log(this.loginForm.value);
 /*Object.keys(this.loginForm.value).map(e => {
  console.log(">>>>>>>",this.loginForm.value[e]);
 });*/

 this.authService.getUserDetails();
}
```

}
Because of form is invalid, login button is also not enabled.
Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add formControlName to your inputs such as:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" formControlName="username" placeholder="Username"/>
      <div *ngIf="f.username.touched && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

For validity check I would use loginform.valid, this should return false when the form is invalid

Comment: yes, it is updating the form value after adding the formControlName attribute to fieldes. But it is not showing errors when I submitt the form.

Comment: I made a note to use !loginform.valid, "not" valid and invalid are not quite the same:

https://itnext.io/valid-and-invalid-in-angular-forms-61cfa3f2a0cd